# Can someone provide a link to the basic integration theorem?

Tags: integration

Can someone provide a link to the basic integration theorem?

The one given by the father of calculus, "Newton".

$\int {x}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$

Comment: Many would call Newton "one of the two (at least!) parents of calculus"...

Comment: Archimedes had already done the equivalent of the integral of $x^2$, $2000$ years before Newton. Anyway, Newton did not do calculus exercises. The first thing he did with his new method was to solve the problem of the motion of the moon.

Comment: For some reason I find it incredibly funny that you have put Newton's name in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the *original* paper on that I can't help you, but if you're looking only for a proof I can, and I'm afraid that it is boringly simple:

By definition:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+c\right)=x\Longrightarrow \int x\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+C(=\text{constant})$$

Comment: You may need the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Answer (score 1):

William Dunham's "The Calculus Gallery: Masterpieces from Newton to Lebesgue" (Princeton University Press, 2009) discusses several of the early theorems in calculus in (nearly) the original form, including Newton's integration of $x^{m/n}$ (not just $x^2$). Haven't got it handy, sorry.